# GDAL C# Style class

Tags: c#, gdal

I'm using C# SDK for GDAL from GISInternals (http://www.gisinternals.com/).
I convert kml to geojson and want to use styles defined in kml.
However, when I read StylesTable, I only get string representation of style,
not an instance of some style.
Are there in C# SDK implementations of classes like OGRStyleBrush,
OGRStyleLabel, OGRStyleMgr, OGRStylePen, OGRStyleSymbol, or do I need to
parse style string I get on my own?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

None, classes related to vectors in Ogr(Gdal) don't support style definitions for vector map visualization.